# Ruby + Action Web Service + SOAP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap, actionwebservice

I have a task to develop a web-service using AWS and SOAP. But both of them seem to be deprecated now. I found only one guide which fits my demands - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ws-rubyrails/index.html , but it was written in 2008 and things have changed a lot since then.

So could anyone give me a link to a tutorial which includes AWS and SOAP? Thanks.

Comment: For SOAP: http://railscasts.com/episodes/290-soap-with-savon I don't know about AWS. Good luck

Comment: I really need to take advantage of Action Web Services. Besides that, Savon is a CLIENT, and I need a SERVICE.

Comment: Sadly, that Railscast is outdated. But there's a lot of up to date [documentation for Savon](http://savonrb.com/version2.html).

Comment: For a server, I would suggest you take a look at [WashOut](https://github.com/inossidabile/wash_out).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I figured out this question and here is the answer: you need to downgrade to Rails 1.x.x and follow the tutorials. Unfortunately, my searches during the month gave no results about AWS working on Rails 2 or Rails 3.

Comment: AWS works fine on Rails 2.3 and there's a fork that works on Rails 3, but there doesn't seem to be one for Rails 4. Anyways, I'd recommend wash_out instead of AWS, the project is still very much alive, unlike AWS and it's forks. AWS is also tied to the dead soap4r package.